# awk: print first line in which a field condition is met

Tags: printing, awk, line, conditional-statements

I know it's a ridiculously simple problem, but I'd like to print the first line in many files for which a given field condition is met:

```
$ awk ' ( $3>=0.2 ) { print $3, $5 } ' Data.out
```

I've tried to insert END in a few places to exit printing, but I can't get it to work...  The above prints ALL the lines for which $3>=0.2...

Comment: `END` doesn't stop the program, it executes after all lines have been read.

Answer (score 4):

The first thing that springs to mind is to add `exit`:

```
awk '$3 >= 0.2 { print $3, $5; exit }' file
```

But unless that's all you want to do, you will need a flag:

```
awk '$3 >= 0.2 && !f { print $3, $5; f=1 }' file
```

Comment: I get a 'limit number' error, again.  I think MKS awk is broken under Win 7 Pro...   Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

The command you are looking for is [nextfile](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Nextfile-Statement.html):

```
gawk '$3 >= 0.2 { print $3, $5; nextfile }' *.out
```

If you're not using gawk, [here](http://docs.freebsd.org/info/gawk/gawk.info.Next_File_Statement.html) is some advice for simulating this behaviour in other awks. It has however made it into the 2012 POSIX standard as per the note on the gnu page.

Answer (score 0):

`awk ' ( $3>=0.2 ) { print $3, $5; exit } ' Data.out`

Comment: I get an error message 'limit number' (MKS Toolkit 9.2, Win 7 Pro)...  Same error with gawk, with single and double quotes...

Comment: You get that error if you add `exit` like I suggested? But not without it?

Comment: Yes, both with awk and gawk, in cmd and ksh.  If there's no 'exit', I get a printout of all lines with $3>0.2 in awk, but an single-quote error in gawk.  I shoudl add that there are reports of Win 7 Pro breaking MKS Toolkit pipes etc., so who knows...

Answer (score 0):

The problem with `exit` (apart from the apparent compatibility issue you have) is that it will not process the next file at all if you have multiple files. Here is a script for multiple files:

```
awk 'FNR==1{f=1}
    $3>=0.2{if(f)print $3,$5;f=0}' file1 file2 ...
```

You may be able to optimize by e.g. closing the input file after the first match, but this should at least get you started.